# Collection name auto convert to plural in reactjs and mogoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I want to create collection name's "party" and a request getAll data. My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let PartySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        partyId: String,
        partyName: String,
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Party', PartySchema)
```

And my controller:

```
const Party = require('./../models/Party')
module.exports = {
    getAll: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(Party.find());
        Party.find().exec((err, party)=> {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            else if (!party)
                res.send(404)
            else
                res.send(party)
            next()            
        })
    },
}
```

Console.log show me collectionName is "parties" not "party". What's wrong in hear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mongoose try to infer collection name by making your shema in plural form.

However, you can force your collection name with [second parameter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema):

```
let PartySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        partyId: String,
        partyName: String,
    }, 
    { collection: 'your_collection_name' } 
);
```

Comment: Cảm ơn a @Mạnh Quyết nha, e mới học nên vụ này gà quá, mong a giúp đỡ thêm :)

Comment: Welcome em :D~~

Comment: Anh @Mạnh Quyết, Em hỏi chút, em đang thắc mắc luồng data như sau: 
Component import các actions, sau đó client có các event gọi tới actions của em. Actions sẽ trả về object và dispatch một type nào đó để gọi reducer update state của component. Tuy nhiên em lại chưa tìm thấy nó update cho Component nào hay là chính component phát sinh event client phía trên ạ ? tks a nhé!

Comment: I dont know react :D anh không rành react đâu em

Comment: ồ, tks a nhé, e tưởng a rành vụ này :)

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose runs through all collection names through a function that pluralises collection names using a fn called `toCollectionName`. You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L31